# Deriving projection operator for an affine set

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given an affine set $Ax=b$, the Projection operator to this set is $$P(z) = z - A^{T}(AA^{T})^{-1}(Az-b)$$ which is also affine.

How is this derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(z)$ solves the problem 
$$
\min \|z -x\|^2
$$
subject to the constraint
$$
Ax=b.
$$
The KKT system is a necessary and sufficient optimality condition (why?):
$$
Ax = b, \ A^T\mu = x-z.
$$
Multiply the second equation by $A$, assume $(AA^T)^{-1}$ being invertible, then
solve for $\mu$, then solve for $z$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. KKT is necessary and sufficient because strong duality obtains.